# What is making my bootstrap modal disappear on the second time I toggle it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal with a form inside. The save button makes a post request (via ajax) and then the modal is dismissed using the code below inside the success function.

```
$("#my-modal-id").modal("hide");
$("body").removeClass("modal-open");
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();
```

The first time I toggle the modal or if I just cancel the modal, without saving it, I can (re)open it without problem, the issue is after making the ajax request for the first time.

If I click the button that toggles the modal for the **second** time, it rapidly disappears (the backdrop remains) and to toggle it again I need to refresh the page. When I inspect the page, I see that there is a display attribute set to none on my modal div.

I tried changing from $("#my-modal-id").modal("hide") to $("#my-modal-id").modal("toggle") but it still didn't work.

I am using jQuery v. 2.2.4 (unfortunately).
Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Comment: without the code that is causing the issue we cannot help much. Please include your `HTML` and `CSS` code as well.

Comment: why not just `$('#my-modal-id').modal('hide')`

Comment: @ITgoldman, tried that too. The background stays in the page and prevents me from doing anything else on the page.

Comment: @Ewertonews can you post your html? I had the same problem a time ago and if I didn't forgot it was related to bootstrap classes.

Comment: You don't by chance have multiple modals open?- having them stacked.. I find that throws a giant monkey wrench in it